# Aligning a JPG/PNG image within a rectangular border

Tags: css, svg

I am using <image> elements to position raster images within the borders of <rect> elements. This works OK, but in the general case I do not know the aspect ratio of the raster images. When SVG scales them to fit within the confines of a rectangular area then it appears to align them (assuming aspect is preserved) middle and centre. I actually want to align them top and centre but I can't seem to find the right way to do this.

Comment: can you provide some code for example of your case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet"` to your `<image>` element.

Comment: I would never have found that. Thanks.